# How to match string containing plus symbol (+) in scala?

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to match two string which has '+' symbol in it.

```
val mystring = "test+string"
val tomatch = "test+string"

mystring.matches(tomatch)
This returns False.
```

tried to escape the + with \+ however it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaping `+` is correct, as `\+` matches a literal `+`. There are more characters that need to be escaped in regex patterns, see [What special characters must be escaped in regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399078/what-special-characters-must-be-escaped-in-regular-expressions)

In Scala, you may use `"""...."""` triple-quoted string literal to use just 1 backslash. See the [Scala regex help](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/util/matching/Regex.html):

> Since escapes are not processed in multi-line string literals, using triple quotes avoids having to escape the backslash character, so that `"\\d"` can be written `"""\d"""`. The same result is achieved with certain interpolators, such as `raw"\d".r` or a custom interpolator `r"\d"` that also compiles the `Regex`.

So, use

```
val mystring = "test+string"
val tomatch = """test\+string"""
mystring.matches(tomatch)
```

See the [Scala demo](http://rextester.com/KDT18787)

Else, in a regular (non-"raw") string literal, you would need double backslashes:

```
val tomatch = "test\\+string"
```

**If a whole string pattern should be treated as a literal string**, use

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
```

and then

```
val tomatch = Regex.quote("test+string")
```

The `Regex.quote` will escape all special chars that should be escaped correctly.

[Another Scala demo](http://rextester.com/EBY23487)

Comment: Thank you Wiktor.

Comment: Looks like scala 2.10 doesn't have Regex.quote to match as a literal string. Any other options for scala 2.10? @Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: @sandyyyy Use Java's `Pattern.quote`.